# Is there a way to parallelize multiple-matrix multiplication in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, parallel-processing, matrix-multiplication

I am trying to multiply around 500-1000 numpy matrices and repeat this around 1000 times. I have succesfully parallelized the repetition part and obtaining 2x speed up (for parameters that I am using). Is there any way I can parallelize the matrix multiplication?

Since matrix multiplication is not commutative I don't think I can do this trivially using Pool.map() as I did for repetition step. The only way I can think of parallelising this is by dividing 1000 matrices into sets of 2 adjacent ones and multiply each separately to get 500 matrices and then repeat the step. But I do not know if there is any pre-written algorithm for this or any simple way of doing this.

e.g -

[image]

Please do suggest me a method or even some reference would be fine.

Comment: Could you add minimal representative sample data and expected output? Or a working solution (with loops even)?

Comment: `np.linalg.multi_dot` evaluates a chained multiplication while attempting to use the optimal order.  But that maters only if the dimensions differ enough.  It doesn't attempt to pass anything off to multiple processes.  Still it may be worth your while to look at its code.

Comment: @Divakar The matrix contains complex floats. I'll try update the question with a working solution

Comment: @hpaulj I read some posts regarding multi_dot and also tried it myself. It turns that that multi_dot is significantly slower(say 100x) than iterative regular dot product. This is because my matrices are regular 3x3 with float and multi-dot gains speed only in case of much bigger matrices and if matrices are irregular shape and not with large number of matrices. Apprently it wastes time in figuring out the best way to multiply it seems. Thanks though!